# How can I combine two columns (Name.x & Name.y) that have resulted from merging the datasets from a common column?

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I am new to R and I am really stuck on something that is probably a very simple task. I have merged two datasets by a common column (unique ID). This has been fine but there were a few columns present in both the datasets and this has resulted in two columns (Name.x & Name.Y).

I want to move the information in Name.Y to the Name.X column & then delete the Name.Y column. Basically I want to replace the NA in Name.X to the names given in Name.Y

I have tried to us the is.na function but it does not work:

```
df1$Name.y[which(is.na(df1$Name.y))] <- df1$Name.x
```

This is probably super simple but I have struggled for a while trying to do this. I have also tried unite function but it did not work either.

Comment: It is probably easier to alter the merge/join-code, to prevent the formation of unwated colunm(s) completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subset *both* vectors according to the `NA` values in column `df$Name.y`; otherwise you are trying to put the *whole* of `df$Name.x` into the *subset* of `df1$Name.y` that has `NA` values:

```
df1$Name.y[is.na(df1$Name.y)] <- df1$Name.x[is.na(df1$Name.y)]
```